# Wrong lines in d3.js chart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, d3.js, charts

I don't know why I have some wrong lines in d3.js chart. I'm not sure it's a problem of coding because if I try to change tab on Chrome and then to go back to the chart's tab, wrong lines disappear.

It's not easy to understand what is the problem, all' add an image to explain better.

[image: Wrong Chart]

This is javascript code that updates the chart (I'm working with Vue.js)

```
           const line = d3.line()
                            .x((_d,i) => this.xScale(this.zoom* i))
                            .y(d => this.yScale(d))
                            .curve(d3.curveBasis);
            
            this.svg.select('#g-path').select('path')
            .attr('d', line(this.data))
            
            .style("stroke-linejoin", "round")
            .style('fill', 'none')
            .style('stroke', 'green')
            .style('stroke-width', 1);
```

EDIT: Lines disappear also if I click on another component in the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this might be an issue with the miter

> *When two line segments meet at a sharp angle and miter joins have been specified for stroke-linejoin, it is possible for the miter to extend far beyond the thickness of the line stroking the path. The stroke-miterlimit ratio is used to define when the limit is exceeded, if so the join is converted from a miter to a bevel.*
> [*src*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-miterlimit)

Although a round line join shouldn't be causing the issues, there may be some calculation errors when the lines get really close.

You could try a miter line join that will prevent the lines from extending.

```js
  .style("stroke-linejoin", "miter")
  .style("miter-clip", "1")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried to change stroke-linejoin but nothing changes. I used exactly your code. I think the problem could be something related to path dimensions because when d3.js updates the path variable everything that is outside the path (such as wrong lines) it's not updated and so you can see extra lines. @Daniel

Comment: is it something that can be inspected with dev tools? Is it chrome only?

Answer (score 0):

Ok probably i solved the problem. Another thing i had to do with the chart was to make it responsive and for this reason I used a viewBox for svg element. Adding the viewBox seems to have solved the issue.

I'll add the code so everyone with the same problem can solve it easily.

**Javascript:**

```
             this.svg = d3.select("#chart")
             .append("svg")
             .attr("viewBox", `0 0 800 420`);
```

**HTML:**

```
<template>
      <div id="chart"></div>
</template>
```

Thanks for the answers!